# SQL Server 2012 Breaking Data Up From One Column Into Multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have three very long columns of data shown below . 
[image]

The Data gets added into the database in 214 line block, each line is the value of a different variable at that time stamp. The time stamp will be the same for each of the 214 lines per block of data. I'm trying to take the blocks and break them up into individual columns/rows (if possible I would like to make this dynamic vs entering each name of a column or row).

Either solution  below would work.

[image]

[image]

I've looked into using PIVOT but it seems like that requires arithmetically combining data not just breaking it out into separate columns/rows.

This will be used to generate an SQL report that may be looked at once a month or so, so performance is not that big of an issue.

---

Dynamic pivot generated by @Rigerta Demiri code below

```
    select TagTimestamp,  AA_Mode, CDR01_Torque_Max, CDR02_Torque_Max, CDR03_Torque_Max, CDR04_Torque_Max, CDR05_Torque_Max, CDR06_Index_Position_0, CDR06_Index_Position_1, CDR06_Torque_Max, CDR07_Index_Position_0, CDR07_Index_Position_1, CDR07_Torque_Max, CDR09_Axis_Offset, CDR09_Torque_Max, CDR10_Torque_Max, CDR11_Torque_Max, CDR12_Torque_Max, CDR13_Torque_Max, CDR14_Index_Position_3, CDR14_Index_Position_4, CDR14_Torque_Max, CDR17_Axis_Offset, CDR17_Slave_Scaling, CDR17_Torque_Max, CDR18_Axis_Offset, CDR18_Slave_Scaling, CDR18_Torque_Max, CDR19_Axis_Offset, CDR19_Slave_Scaling, CDR19_Torque_Max, CDR20_Axis_Offset, CDR20_Slave_Scaling, CDR20_Torque_Max, CDR21_Axis_Offset, CDR21_Slave_Scaling, CDR21_Torque_Max, CDR22_Axis_Offset, CDR22_Slave_Scaling, CDR22_Torque_Max, CDR25_Axis_Offset, CDR25_Slave_Scaling, CDR25_Torque_Max, CDR26_Axis_Offset, CDR26_Slave_Scaling, CDR26_Torque_Max, CDR27_Axis_Offset, CDR27_Slave_Scaling, CDR27_Torque_Max, CDR28_Axis_Offset, CDR28_Slave_Scaling, CDR28_Torque_Max, CDR29_Axis_Offset, CDR29_Slave_Scaling, CDR29_Torque_Max, CDR30_Axis_Offset, CDR30_Slave_Scaling, CDR30_Torque_Max, CDR33_Index_Position_1, CDR33_Index_Position_2, CDR33_Torque_Max, CDR34_Torque_Max, CDR35_Torque_Max, CDR36_Slave_Scaling, CDR36_Torque_Max, CDR37_Slave_Scaling, CDR37_Torque_Max, CDR38_Slave_Scaling, CDR38_Torque_Max, CVFD42_Speed_Comp, CVFD43_Speed_Comp, CVFD44_Speed_Comp, CVFD45_Speed_Comp, CVFD46_Speed_Comp, CVFD47_Speed_Comp, CVFD48_Speed_Comp, Carton_Vac_Pick_Max_Mispick_Limit, Changeover_Points[0], Changeover_Points[100], Changeover_Points[101], Changeover_Points[10], Changeover_Points[11], Changeover_Points[12], Changeover_Points[13], Changeover_Points[14], Changeover_Points[15], Changeover_Points[16], Changeover_Points[17], Changeover_Points[18], Changeover_Points[19], Changeover_Points[1], Changeover_Points[20], Changeover_Points[21], Changeover_Points[22], Changeover_Points[23], Changeover_Points[24], Changeover_Points[25], Changeover_Points[26], Changeover_Points[27], Changeover_Points[28], Changeover_Points[29], Changeover_Points[2], Changeover_Points[30], Changeover_Points[31], Changeover_Points[32], Changeover_Points[33], Changeover_Points[34], Changeover_Points[35], Changeover_Points[36], Changeover_Points[37], Changeover_Points[38], Changeover_Points[39], Changeover_Points[3], Changeover_Points[40], Changeover_Points[41], Changeover_Points[42], Changeover_Points[43], Changeover_Points[44], Changeover_Points[45], Changeover_Points[46], Changeover_Points[47], Changeover_Points[48], Changeover_Points[49], Changeover_Points[4], Changeover_Points[50], Changeover_Points[51], Changeover_Points[52], Changeover_Points[53], Changeover_Points[54], Changeover_Points[55], Changeover_Points[56], Changeover_Points[57], Changeover_Points[58], Changeover_Points[59], Changeover_Points[5], Changeover_Points[60], Changeover_Points[61], Changeover_Points[62], Changeover_Points[63], Changeover_Points[64], Changeover_Points[65], Changeover_Points[66], Changeover_Points[67], Changeover_Points[68], Changeover_Points[69], Changeover_Points[6], Changeover_Points[70], Changeover_Points[71], Changeover_Points[72], Changeover_Points[73], Changeover_Points[74], Changeover_Points[75], Changeover_Points[76], Changeover_Points[77], Changeover_Points[78], Changeover_Points[79], Changeover_Points[7], Changeover_Points[80], Changeover_Points[81], Changeover_Points[82], Changeover_Points[83], Changeover_Points[84], Changeover_Points[85], Changeover_Points[86], Changeover_Points[87], Changeover_Points[88], Changeover_Points[89], Changeover_Points[8], Changeover_Points[90], Changeover_Points[91], Changeover_Points[92], Changeover_Points[93], Changeover_Points[94], Changeover_Points[95], Changeover_Points[96], Changeover_Points[97], Changeover_Points[98], Changeover_Points[99], Changeover_Points[9], Delta_1_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Delta_2_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Delta_2_Loading_Index_4_XZ_0, Delta_2_Loading_Index_4_XZ_1, Delta_2_Loading_Index_6_XZ_0, Delta_2_Loading_Index_6_XZ_1, Delta_2_Loading_Index_7_XZ_0, Delta_2_Loading_Index_7_XZ_1, Delta_3_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Delta_4_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Delta_4_Loading_Index_4_XZ_0, Delta_4_Loading_Index_4_XZ_1, Delta_4_Loading_Index_6_XZ_0, Delta_4_Loading_Index_6_XZ_1, Delta_4_Loading_Index_7_XZ_0, Delta_4_Loading_Index_7_XZ_1, Delta_5_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Delta_6_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Discharge_Carton_Blocked_Delay_On, Discharge_Carton_Dischrage_Jam_Delay, Glue_Low_Level_Supply_Limit, Laner_Conveyor_Product_Count1, Laner_Conveyor_Product_Count2, Laner_Conveyor_Side_Belts_Off_Delay, Machine_Speed, Magazine_Advance_Delay, Magazine_Advance_Fault_Delay, Magzine_Low_Level_ShutDown_Limit, Major_FLap_Inspection_Cons_Fail_Limit, Master_Data_Code, Minor_Flap_Inspection_Cons_Fail_Limit, Outer_Carton_Mode, Recipe_Name, Recipe_Number, ThirtySix_Count_Mode, Vision_Job_Data
              from 
                (
                    select TagTimestamp, TagItemID, TagValue
                    from #allData2
                ) x
              pivot ( max(TagValue) for TagItemID in ( AA_Mode, CDR01_Torque_Max, CDR02_Torque_Max, CDR03_Torque_Max, CDR04_Torque_Max, CDR05_Torque_Max, CDR06_Index_Position_0, CDR06_Index_Position_1, CDR06_Torque_Max, CDR07_Index_Position_0, CDR07_Index_Position_1, CDR07_Torque_Max, CDR09_Axis_Offset, CDR09_Torque_Max, CDR10_Torque_Max, CDR11_Torque_Max, CDR12_Torque_Max, CDR13_Torque_Max, CDR14_Index_Position_3, CDR14_Index_Position_4, CDR14_Torque_Max, CDR17_Axis_Offset, CDR17_Slave_Scaling, CDR17_Torque_Max, CDR18_Axis_Offset, CDR18_Slave_Scaling, CDR18_Torque_Max, CDR19_Axis_Offset, CDR19_Slave_Scaling, CDR19_Torque_Max, CDR20_Axis_Offset, CDR20_Slave_Scaling, CDR20_Torque_Max, CDR21_Axis_Offset, CDR21_Slave_Scaling, CDR21_Torque_Max, CDR22_Axis_Offset, CDR22_Slave_Scaling, CDR22_Torque_Max, CDR25_Axis_Offset, CDR25_Slave_Scaling, CDR25_Torque_Max, CDR26_Axis_Offset, CDR26_Slave_Scaling, CDR26_Torque_Max, CDR27_Axis_Offset, CDR27_Slave_Scaling, CDR27_Torque_Max, CDR28_Axis_Offset, CDR28_Slave_Scaling, CDR28_Torque_Max, CDR29_Axis_Offset, CDR29_Slave_Scaling, CDR29_Torque_Max, CDR30_Axis_Offset, CDR30_Slave_Scaling, CDR30_Torque_Max, CDR33_Index_Position_1, CDR33_Index_Position_2, CDR33_Torque_Max, CDR34_Torque_Max, CDR35_Torque_Max, CDR36_Slave_Scaling, CDR36_Torque_Max, CDR37_Slave_Scaling, CDR37_Torque_Max, CDR38_Slave_Scaling, CDR38_Torque_Max, CVFD42_Speed_Comp, CVFD43_Speed_Comp, CVFD44_Speed_Comp, CVFD45_Speed_Comp, CVFD46_Speed_Comp, CVFD47_Speed_Comp, CVFD48_Speed_Comp, Carton_Vac_Pick_Max_Mispick_Limit, Changeover_Points[0], Changeover_Points[100], Changeover_Points[101], Changeover_Points[10], Changeover_Points[11], Changeover_Points[12], Changeover_Points[13], Changeover_Points[14], Changeover_Points[15], Changeover_Points[16], Changeover_Points[17], Changeover_Points[18], Changeover_Points[19], Changeover_Points[1], Changeover_Points[20], Changeover_Points[21], Changeover_Points[22], Changeover_Points[23], Changeover_Points[24], Changeover_Points[25], Changeover_Points[26], Changeover_Points[27], Changeover_Points[28], Changeover_Points[29], Changeover_Points[2], Changeover_Points[30], Changeover_Points[31], Changeover_Points[32], Changeover_Points[33], Changeover_Points[34], Changeover_Points[35], Changeover_Points[36], Changeover_Points[37], Changeover_Points[38], Changeover_Points[39], Changeover_Points[3], Changeover_Points[40], Changeover_Points[41], Changeover_Points[42], Changeover_Points[43], Changeover_Points[44], Changeover_Points[45], Changeover_Points[46], Changeover_Points[47], Changeover_Points[48], Changeover_Points[49], Changeover_Points[4], Changeover_Points[50], Changeover_Points[51], Changeover_Points[52], Changeover_Points[53], Changeover_Points[54], Changeover_Points[55], Changeover_Points[56], Changeover_Points[57], Changeover_Points[58], Changeover_Points[59], Changeover_Points[5], Changeover_Points[60], Changeover_Points[61], Changeover_Points[62], Changeover_Points[63], Changeover_Points[64], Changeover_Points[65], Changeover_Points[66], Changeover_Points[67], Changeover_Points[68], Changeover_Points[69], Changeover_Points[6], Changeover_Points[70], Changeover_Points[71], Changeover_Points[72], Changeover_Points[73], Changeover_Points[74], Changeover_Points[75], Changeover_Points[76], Changeover_Points[77], Changeover_Points[78], Changeover_Points[79], Changeover_Points[7], Changeover_Points[80], Changeover_Points[81], Changeover_Points[82], Changeover_Points[83], Changeover_Points[84], Changeover_Points[85], Changeover_Points[86], Changeover_Points[87], Changeover_Points[88], Changeover_Points[89], Changeover_Points[8], Changeover_Points[90], Changeover_Points[91], Changeover_Points[92], Changeover_Points[93], Changeover_Points[94], Changeover_Points[95], Changeover_Points[96], Changeover_Points[97], Changeover_Points[98], Changeover_Points[99], Changeover_Points[9], Delta_1_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Delta_2_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Delta_2_Loading_Index_4_XZ_0, Delta_2_Loading_Index_4_XZ_1, Delta_2_Loading_Index_6_XZ_0, Delta_2_Loading_Index_6_XZ_1, Delta_2_Loading_Index_7_XZ_0, Delta_2_Loading_Index_7_XZ_1, Delta_3_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Delta_4_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Delta_4_Loading_Index_4_XZ_0, Delta_4_Loading_Index_4_XZ_1, Delta_4_Loading_Index_6_XZ_0, Delta_4_Loading_Index_6_XZ_1, Delta_4_Loading_Index_7_XZ_0, Delta_4_Loading_Index_7_XZ_1, Delta_5_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Delta_6_Effector_Cycle_Jam_Delay, Discharge_Carton_Blocked_Delay_On, Discharge_Carton_Dischrage_Jam_Delay, Glue_Low_Level_Supply_Limit, Laner_Conveyor_Product_Count1, Laner_Conveyor_Product_Count2, Laner_Conveyor_Side_Belts_Off_Delay, Machine_Speed, Magazine_Advance_Delay, Magazine_Advance_Fault_Delay, Magzine_Low_Level_ShutDown_Limit, Major_FLap_Inspection_Cons_Fail_Limit, Master_Data_Code, Minor_Flap_Inspection_Cons_Fail_Limit, Outer_Carton_Mode, Recipe_Name, Recipe_Number, ThirtySix_Count_Mode, Vision_Job_Data) )p  
          order by TagTimestamp
```

Problem with the above code was that I had special characters '[' and ']' in some of the tag names which caused sql to error out. Removing those characters caused the code to work correctly.

Comment: Please add sample data in text format than Images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [dynamic pivot](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/) would do the work, in case you don't already know all possible `TagItemIDs`. If you do, a simple pivot would also work.

Example code:

```
declare @cols_tagItems as nvarchar(max)
     ,  @cols_tagItems_max as nvarchar(max)
     ,  @query  as nvarchar(max)

select @cols_tagItems = stuff((select distinct ', ' + TagItemID from #table for xml path(''), type ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') ,1,1,'')
 select @cols_tagItems

set @query = 'select TagTimestamp, ' + @cols_tagItems + '
                  from 
                    (
                        select TagTimestamp, TagItemID, TagValue
                        from #table 
                    ) x
                  pivot ( max(TagValue) for TagItemID in (' + @cols_tagItems + ') )p  
              order by TagTimestamp'
select @query
execute sp_executesql @query;
```

You can check out a working demo [here](http://rextester.com/YMOVT82986). 
Please note I only included three `TagItemIds` and just assigned some `TagValues` to them.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at this and let you know how it worked out.

Comment: Your code works just fine the problem was that I had sql special characters in TagItemID '[' and ']' thank you for the help it worked once I removed those characters.

Comment: Happy to help! :)